# Is it possible to find out what options packages were compiled with?

Tags: package-management, vim, compiling

I am interested in knowing which options are used to compile vim in the package "vim" as I am trying to compile vim from source on another system, not running Debian/Ubuntu, and would like it to work in a similar way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Grab the source package

```
apt-get source vim
```

That'll download the source for the package in your current dir. Look at `debian/rules`, which is a makefile used when creating all the different vim packages. It may be hard to read, but the information you seek should be in there somewhere.

You can also download the source package from http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/trusty/vim (scroll down) if you can't log into a debian/ubuntu box to run apt-get.

Comment: Mention that `debian/rules` is in strongswan_{version}-*ubuntu*.debian.tar.xz.

Answer (score 10):

`vim --version` will list all the options in ubuntu.

Comment: It would be very nice if that was consistent across every application.

Answer (score 1):

Version command in vim reports compile options.`:version`